# Method or helper function to return objects from EntityFramework with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, wcf

The following code reads from Microsoft EntityFramework 6.0 domain model and returns the single view_patient object. The view_patient object is defined in the backend database and uploaded to the .edmx model of EF.

I am new to EF, but it seems there should be a better way--(better means less typing)-- of going from model to object without the intermediary anonymous data transfer object. As I have a couple hundred of these procedures to write (all within a WCF service), is there a better way of doing this? Or perhaps a "generic" method that will allow going directly from Link-to-entity to output of objects?

A note towards naming convention:
The classes are coming directly from Npgsql 3.0.5 EntityFramework interface -- which in turn is being read directly from PostgreSQL 9.5 database. I can not seem to get either EF or Npgsql to return PascalCase from the PostgreSQL database which is case-insensitive and, without adding quotes to all names, returns only lowercase names for tables, stored procedures, and columns.

Note #2: When not going through the intermediate DTO, I get the following error:

> The entity or complex type 'chaosModel.view_patient' cannot be
>   constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

(Using .NET 4.5)

```
  // testing the setup
    public view_patient Test(string cpatient)
    {
        using (var ctx = new chaosEntities())
        {

            var q = (from patient in ctx.patients
                     join chart in ctx.charts on patient.chart_recid equals chart.recid
                     where patient.cpatient == cpatient
                     select new
                     {
                         birthdate = patient.birthdate,
                         chart_number = chart.chart_number,
                         chart_recid = chart.recid,
                         city = patient.city,
                         cpatient = patient.cpatient,
                         donotsee = chart.donotsee,
                         firstname = patient.firstname,
                         groupid = chart.groupid,
                         lastname = patient.lastname,
                         mailbox = patient.mailbox,
                         mi = patient.mi,
                         patient_recid = patient.recid,
                         phone = patient.phone,
                         selfpay = chart.selfpay,
                         cashonly = chart.cashonly,
                         sex = patient.sex,
                         ssn = patient.ssn,
                         state = patient.state,
                         street = patient.street,
                         zipcode = patient.zipcode
                     });

            var r = (from c in q.AsEnumerable()
                     select new view_patient
                     {
                         birthdate = c.birthdate.ToShortDateString(),
                         chart_number = c.chart_number,
                         chart_recid = c.chart_recid,
                         city = c.city,
                         cpatient = c.cpatient,
                         donotsee = c.donotsee,
                         firstname = c.firstname,
                         groupid = c.groupid,
                         lastname = c.lastname,
                         mailbox = c.mailbox,
                         mi = c.mi,
                         patient_recid = c.patient_recid,
                         phone = c.phone,
                         selfpay = c.selfpay,
                         cashonly = c.cashonly,
                         sex = c.sex,
                         ssn = c.ssn,
                         state = c.state,
                         street = c.street,
                         zipcode = c.zipcode
                     }).SingleOrDefault();

            return r;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please remember to add language tags to your posts as well.

Comment: You seem to actually want some form of "automapping" (iterating with reflection over object fields/properties and matching them). There seems to be [Automapper Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) and here is [Tutorial for it](http://bengtbe.com/blog/2009/04/14/using-automapper-to-map-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc/). If I remember correctly, it have some tricks to perform better than raw reflections (which are always slow) - someday I will migrate my EF code to it.... someday ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the naming that should more C# friendly (PascalCase), the application should have a clear separation between data models and view models.

Data models are usually generated automatically in database first scenarios or POCOs classes defined by the programmer (code-first approach) and should be separated from view models or data returned by the service layer which usually consists in aggregated information.

Ok, for your particular case, data model is `Patient`:

```
public partial class Patient
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String Cpatient { get; set; }

    // rest of properties come here
}
```

and your view model can be called `PatientViewModel`:

```
public partial class PatientViewModel
{
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDateStr 
    { 
        get { return BirthDate .ToShortDateString(); }
    }

    public String ChartNumber { get; set; }
    public ChartRecid { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
    public String Cpatient { get; set; }
}
```

So, as you can see, the view model hold the properties required by the view, which are aggregated from multiple data models.

**Getting data model extra data**

One method I found convenient (although not exactly orthodox, since it pollutes data models) is to extend the data model with properties that provide extra needed data, like this:

```
// this is another part of the partial class
public partial class Patient
{
    public String ChartNumber 
    { 
       get { return Chart.chart_number; }
       set { Chart.chart_number = value; }
    }

    public ChartRecid 
    { 
       get { return Chart.ChartRecid; }
       set { Chart.ChartRecid = value; }
    }

    // other "computed" properties come here
}
```

An alternative to this approach is to have custom map these properties when transferring data model -> view model and vice-versa (so, this also supports data persistence, not just data fetch).

**Actual mapping**

As already suggested, [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) was specially designed for this kind of chores. Its usage is simple as:

**setup the mapping:**

(this is deprecated in the last version, as described [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/21/removing-the-static-api-from-automapper/) (and also mentioned by the compiler, if last NuGet package is referenced))

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Patient, PatientViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<PatientViewModel>();
```

**using it:**

```
var patientDataModels = ctx.patients.
   .Include(p => p.Chart)               // eager load chart data
   .Where(p => cpatient == cpatient)
   .ToList();                           

var patientVms = new List<PatientViewModel>();
// Mapper should also handle collection mapping automatically, if type mapping is set up
Mapper.Map(patientDataModels, patientVms);

// if data model is not extended, you have to manually map Chart type properties
```

Eager load is recommended to avoid separate queries generated when Chart object properties are required (less SQL verbosity, significantly faster for large collections).

`AutoMapper` will automatically map properties having the same (and type, if type is different and no implicit conversion can be done, it will throw an exception) and not ignored (`IgnoreMap` attribute).

Comment: I will try it out. The idea of manually creating the classes in code on a database first project where there are hundreds of tables is not particularly interesting to me. Thanks.

Comment: No, in a database first approach, data models are automatically generated using edmx editor (until EF 6, in EF 7 I think there is/will not be one). Of course, view models have to be written.

Comment: I'm new to all this. Please explain "No, in a database first approach...". Thanks.

Comment: @AlanWayne - for existing databases, `Entity Framework database first` is used to generate database context (e.g. `chaosEntities`) and classes for each selected table (e.g. `patient`). More details (step by step, actually) are provided [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database). So, all data models like `patient` are automatically generated. Data model extensions (partial classes) and view models are manually written, however this effort pays when mapping logic is greatly simplified.